# Pasting Inkscape vectors on Krita

Tags: inkscape, svg, krita, copy-and-paste

I have some projects on Inkscape that I would like to transport to Krita as there are more tools there. However, when I copy them and then paste them on Krita, nothing is pasted. I tried both with the shortcut cmd + V and by right-clicking and selecting "paste". I also tried to open the .svg file with Krita and it does not show as an app I can open an .svg file with. In some forums, people say they do it with no problems.

I would please like to know if there is something extra I need to do or if there is any sort of trick.

I am using a MacBook.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Krita can import SVGs, and you can also copy and paste SVGs into Krita from an Inkscape document, most of the time. I've noticed some glitches from time to time, so it's not perfect.  Probably best to make sure the vectors are as simple as possible - just strokes and fills, no filters or path effects.

Comment: oh... I have plenty of paths... Would you recommend any way to go around this?

Comment: Path effects are not the same as paths. Path are fine, path effects probably not.

Comment: oopsie... I'm new here. Forgive my ignorance. Could you please give me (or guide me to) an example of a path effect?

Comment: Path effects are things like Bsplines, Spiro paths, PowerStrokes, Pattern along a path, etc. These effects modify a path.  You can see if one has been applied to a path by opening the Path Effects dialog.

Answer (score 1):

According to the web page for Krita, it is a raster editor program. Inkscape is a vector editor program and the two files are of different construction/composition.

You can, however, export your work as a PNG and select the entire document or individual components to be saved. PNG is a raster format and will be accepted by Krita.

The PNG export is in the file menu in Windows, not sure on the Mac version.

Additional research presents this gem from the [Krita document page](https://docs.krita.org/en/general_concepts/file_formats/file_svg.html):

> While you can open up SVG files with any text-editor to edit them, it
>   is best to use a vector program like Inkscape. Krita 2.9 to 3.3
>   supports importing SVG via the add shape docker. Since Krita 4.0, SVGs
>   can be properly imported, and you can export singlevector layers via
>   Layer ‣ Import/Export ‣ Save Vector Layer as SVG… menu item. For 4.0,
>   Krita will also use SVG to save vector data into its internal format.

Post install notes.

I downloaded the current 4.2.9 version and loaded a couple of SVG files. The first one did not appear, while the second one did. I had created both of these original SVG files and the only significant difference is that one of them had the objects in the drawing outside of the document boundaries. Once I adjusted document properties accordingly, both SVGs open, as vector files in Krita.

If you don't have a current version, that may be a factor, but you can also check your SVG object locations in a number of ways. I'm not a code-monkey, so I can't read the direct code. It's easier for me to open Inkscape and adjust there.

Comment: I would like to continue using the vectors. If I export them as .png this wouldn't be possible. My intention is to use Krita to make an animation and take advantage of its brushed on the vector project I did...

Comment: added update to answer